# Is there a better way to store Javascript class object somewhere for later use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Is there a way to store _MYOBJ in the database for later use?

`let _MYOBJ = new ClassName(args);`

Use case: I have an event channel that stays open for incoming events but sometimes I have to subscribe to more events on that channel. To Subscribe to more events I do need to access that object. Currently, I store all the objects for the channels in a global variable like below.

`` _TENANT_CHANNEL_OBJECT[`${_TENANT_ID}`] = _MYOBJ; ``

So that when I need it I can use the global object. Which works fine, however, I am not sure if that's a best practice.

Can someone suggest an alternate perhaps?

Comment: Rather than something global, consider having a *module* for that sort of thing - explicit dependencies make code a lot more maintainable

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that you want to store this data somewhere other than in your application memory--that could cause your application to crash and lose the data, and may cause you problems in cloud-hosted environments. You'll want it in a database or in a similar data store.

When `_MYOBJ` is a class instance like you have above, it's probably not a good idea to store it in the database. You definitely don't want to store code in your database, just data. So a class in JavaScript (which is really an object under the hood), with methods and a prototype chain and such, isn't a good candidate.

However. NoSQL databases like MongoDB, and even certain SQL databases such as Postgresql, allow you to store JSON objects in your database. This may be what you're looking for.

I'm not sure what your channel objects look like, but as long as they don't contain functions, and you can serialize them into JSON data, you can write them to your DB and read them later.

You'll want to look at the docs for whatever database and/or library you're using to find how to store your data.

Also, it's not a database, but [Redis](https://redis.io/) is a fantastic key/value external memory cache that also gives you pub/sub out of the box, is super-easy to use, and has a fine node.js SDK. It may be redundant or unnecessary depending on your setup.

Finally, forgive me if I'm just going too far off-topic here, but if you're unfamiliar with the concept of ORMs, they will change your life, they are a dream for having your application interface with a database--I've had good results with [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/#/)

Comment: I did store the object in the local storage however, I do have functions that I need to access. but with the existing code when I restart the application I do lose the object but ideally, if I have the object including functions, timers, subscription ids then I don't have to worry about resubscribing to all events.

Comment: I see. Although it's tempting, you should never store code in a data store: it can be a big security vulnerability, and will cause you a ton of grief when say, pushing updates. You should be able to store the data only, and when your application runs, you can read the data into your class/object/function/whatever, which can then interface with the rest of your application. I can't give you a better-detailed example without knowing all the details, but your use-case still sounds well-suited to Redis or similar

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of data is relatively small and you don't need a database, perhaps you could serialize the data and store it locally. You could perhaps use just a cookie, or you might be able to utilize Local Storage.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage